# Android - Can't set view to match_parent height inside card for recycler view

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have a recycler view which is fed with a card_view that has a color bar (a view) on the left edge which is supposed to occupy the whole height of the card.

I tried setting the height of the color view to match_parent but if I do it like this, the color never appears. If I instead assign a number to the height then it works, but I need the view to adjust to the card's height.

Here is the XML for the card that will feed the recycler view:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >


    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingEnd="14dp"
         >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/swatch"
            android:layout_width="12dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pathTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/swatch"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="@string/placeholder_title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pathDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/pathTitle"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/swatch"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="@string/placeholder_title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can I get the "swatch" view to adjust to the height of the card?

Comment: Views inside ConstraintLayout should not use match_parent as width/height. Use 0dp instead. Also, it is better to avoid using RelativeLayout. ConstraintLayout can handle the layout instead and do it more efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it will solve your problem

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <View
            android:id="@+id/swatch"
            android:layout_width="12dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pathTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="@string/placeholder_title"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pathDescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="@string/placeholder_title"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```